# How to get type info from Go compiled packages in language x?

Tags: parsing, go

I want to write a simple editor with basic autocomplete functionality for the Go language as a pet project. How would one go about doing it? I took a look at the Go plugins for Eclipse and IntelliJ, but they were too big for me to comprehend (not to mention getting one to compile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go standard library offers the building blocks for a [Go parser](http://golang.org/pkg/go/) which
you can use to parse the source files and look for function definitions and the like.

There's also the [`godoc`](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Run_godoc_on_package_sources) command which
already does what you want: extracting method definitions and it's documentation. You may look in the 
[source code](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/#cmd%2Fgodoc) to see how `godoc` is 
working or use `godoc` directly.

[This editor written in Go](https://github.com/mikhailt/tabby) projects has a manageable amount of code, 
you may look into it.

Answer (score 2):

The de facto standard approach to this problem is to use [nsf's gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode). I have tried it only in Vim - it works very well.

Even though there's ready made support for specific editors, gocode is not editor specific. It's a daemon with a communication protocol. It is thus usable from any program.